# Correctly importing enumerations in Python

Tags: python, import, enums, enumeration

Let's assume the following scenario. In the directory `./lib` I have the file `animal_enum.py` (`./lib/animal_enum`):

```
from enum import Enum

class Animal(Enum):
    DOG = 1
    CAT = 2
    COW = 3
    
def get_cat():
    return Animal.CAT
```

In the source directory I have the file `./animal_test.py`:

```
def animal_test1():
    from lib.animal_enum import Animal
    from lib.animal_enum import get_cat
    
    print("Results from animal_test1():")
    print(Animal.CAT, get_cat())
    print(Animal.CAT == get_cat())

def animal_test2():
    from lib.animal_enum import Animal
    
    import sys
    sys.path.insert(0, './lib')
    from animal_enum import get_cat
    
    print("Results from animal_test2():")
    print(Animal.CAT, get_cat())
    print(Animal.CAT == get_cat())
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    animal_test1()
    print('-----')
    animal_test2()
```

In both cases, the enumeration is imported as `from lib.animal_enum import Animal`. The difference is how I import the function `get_cat()`. In the function `animal_test1()` it is done directly by `from lib.animal_enum import get_cat`, in the function `animal_test2()` the path to the `lib` directory is added to the `sys.path` variable and the method is imported as `from animal_enum import get_cat`.

Now I compare the value `Animal.CAT` to the result of the function `get_cat`, which is also `Animal.CAT`. I expect both comparisons to be `True`. But instead I get the follwing:

```
Results from animal_test1():
Animal.CAT Animal.CAT
True
-----
Results from animal_test2():
Animal.CAT Animal.CAT
False
```

**Why does the second comparison evaluates to `False`?**

*PS*: One way to prevent this error is for the animal enumeration to inherit from both `int` and `Enum`:

```
class Animal(int, Enum):
    DOG = 1
    CAT = 2
    COW = 3
```

Now, in `animal_test`, integer values are compared and the result is what I expect:

```
Results from animal_test1():
Animal.CAT Animal.CAT
True
-----
Results from animal_test2():
Animal.CAT Animal.CAT
True
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eventhough you import the same module via different ways, python doesn't know they are the same modules. It still thinks `lib.animal_enum` and `animal_enum` are totally different

```
>>> from lib.animal_enum import Animal
>>> from animal_enum import Animal as Animal2
>>> 
>>> Animal == Animal2
False
>>> 
>>> id(Animal)
94046433019280
>>> id(Animal2)
94046433018336
>>> 
>>> Animal.__module__
'lib.animal_enum'
>>> 
>>> Animal2.__module__
'animal_enum'
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But doesn't this behavior make the enum `Animal(Enum)` quite unsuable since I have to rely on that it is imported in the same way? Especially in bigger projects this might be a problem.

Comment: You should always use a consistent way of importing all your modules. If you are going to modify `sys.path`, that should be the first thing you have to do. Also have a look @ `site.addsitedir` - https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#site.addsitedir